# Query with join in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to write this query in laravel, but i don't know how to write it

```
Select RANKED.rankTotal*MATCHED.Popularity score
     , urlID  
  from 
     ( SELECT sum(rank) as rankTotal
            , urlID 
         FROM searchengine.indexer
        where keyword IN("there","is") 
        group 
           by urlID 
     ) RANKED
     , 
     ( Select ID
            , Popularity 
          From searchengine.visitedpages 
         where document LIKE '%there is%'
     ) MATCHED
 where RANKED.urlID = MATCHED.ID ;
```

Comment: You should take a look at how laravels [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) works, it will also help you to make your queries more easy to read.

Answer (score -1):

See if this works for you:

```
$query = \DB::raw("Select RANKED.rankTotal*MATCHED.Popularity as score, urlID  from (SELECT  
                   sum(rank) as rankTotal,urlID 
                   FROM searchengine.indexer
                   where   (keyword=? or keyword=?) group by urlID ) as RANKED, 
                   (Select ID, Popularity 
                   From searchengine.visitedpages where document LIKE ?)  as MATCHED
                   where RANKED.urlID =MATCHED.ID ;");

$results = \DB::select($query, ['there', 'is', '%there is%']);
```

Comment: I'm not a stackoverflow regular. So could someone please explain the downvotes?

Comment: This is not what the op asked for, this is just throwing the normal SQl into laravel and let it handle it.

Comment: `'I need to write this query in laravel'` - because of this phrase i thought he knew there is this other way, the query builder, but he didn't know how to use it/ what to look exactly for. I may be wrong, but the alternative to the query builder would be in my opinion to just run standard `mysqli_*` or `PDO` functions.